# Wacom gets stuck in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, wacom, graphics-tablet

I have a Wacom Bamboo small that worked well in Ubuntu 18.04. I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 and drivers were installed automatically. Wacom tablet works and is detected until I click anything. From that point, the tablet does not work until I reconnect the usb. The mouse works properly during all events.

Has anyone else faced this? Could you please let me know if there is a fix?

Answer (score 1):

Tried out various options.
What worked:

```
lsmod | grep wacom
sudo rmmod wacom
sudo modprobe wacom
```

And reboot

Comment: the command "sudo rmmod wacom" suddenly made my laptop to reboot. External drives mount points got messed up, dunno why.